# no operator found which takes a left operand... (using a class template)

Tags: c++, templates

I'm overloading operators of a class template and I get the error: **Error  1   error C2678: binary '>' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const CSet < int >'**

CSet.h:

```
bool CSet<T>::operator>(const CSet<T>& mySet) const{

    bool flag = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < mySet.size; j++){
            if (arr[i] == mySet[j]){
                flag = true;
                break;
            }
            if (j == mySet.size - 1 && flag == false)
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

void CSet<T>::operator+=(T& myVal){
    T* temp = new T[size + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        if (arr[i] == myVal){
            delete[] temp;
            return;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        temp[i] = arr[i];
    delete[] arr;
    arr = temp;
    arr[size] = myVal;
}
```

mian.cpp:

```
#include "Set.h"


int main(){
    CSet<int> mySet, yourSet;
    mySet += 3; mySet += 4; mySet += 5;
    yourSet += 5; yourSet += 4; yourSet += 3;
    bool boom;
    boom = mySet == yourSet;
}
```

Now, from the error I understand that the compiler cannot convert T into an int. 
My question is: why not? Isn't this the whole purpose of templates?
There must be something that's I'm missing because this doesn't make sense (at least to me).

Comment: How are you defining `operator ==`?

Comment: @Alejandro Oh, I completely forgot about that xD.  It just checks if the two sets are equivalent.  Do you want me to add the definition ?

Comment: Although unrelated to your question, you may want to move the `T* temp = new T[size + 1];` in your `operator +=` until after the first `for` loop. Why bother allocating an array if you're just going to have to deallocate soon after? Or, you could use `std::vector`  , `std::move` your old `vector` into it, and reap the benefits of a `vector` ! :)

Comment: @Alejandro Makes sense, thank you for the advice.  However, as far as I love vectors I'm not allowed to use them since this is homework and we have restrictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely want/need to change it to:

```
bool CSet<T>::operator>(const CSet<T>& mySet) const {
    // ...                                    ^^^^^ Note addition here.
```

When you invoke this member function like:

```
if (x > y) ...
```

It's equivalent to: `if (x.operator>(y))`. The `const` on the parameter type means the right operand can be `const`. To allow the left operand to be `const` as well, you add `const` where it's shown above.

Comment: Now I'm getting the error: Error 1 error C2244: 'CSet<T>::operator >' : unable to match function definition to an existing declaration.  What does that mean?

Comment: Did you add the new `const`  specifier in the header file?

Comment: I did.  And also, do I still need to add the const specifier even if I want the left operand to be modifiable?

Comment: @JamesSonnino: You need the `const` on both the declaration and the definition.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I did, and I edited the question.  Now I'm getting an error which says that the operator += is illegal for the class and "binary '+=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)".  Now I'm not using const for this operator, so what is the problem here?

Comment: The problem is that you're trying to pass literals to a function that takes a reference to a non-const. You can make it a reference to const, pass by value or pass an rvalue reference.